# WPF - TreeView - How to programmatically extract the style of a TreeViewItem (selected style)

Tags: wpf, styles, treeview, code-behind, treeviewitem

I want to assign a new DataTrigger programmatically (in code/not xaml) to every "TreeViewItem" style like I do in the following xaml.

I did some code (under xaml) where I defined my trigger but "ItemContainerStyle" is null. The function is called on Window Initialize event.

Anybody has an idea what I'm doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

I found some part of my problem: I moved my style from the "Resource" section to the "ItemContainerStyle" section as defined below in code sample. This way the style is still applied and I can access the style from the TReeView.ItemContainerStyle property in code. But I still don't know how to get the TreeViewItem selected style like the color of the background by code ??

I have xaml:

```
                <TreeView Name="TreeViewSelectScopeStudy" MinHeight="24" Margin="7" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TvItemRootPssTreeViewRoot.ChildsView}" Height="Auto"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsHilighted}" Value="true">
                                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="SlateBlue"></Setter>-->
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
```

I have that code:

```
    public static void EnableMultipleSelection(TreeView treeView)
    {
        if (!_isMultiSelectTreeViewLeftButtonHandlerRegistered)
        {
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TreeViewItem), UIElement.MouseDownEvent,
                                                             new MouseButtonEventHandler(TreeViewMouseDownGlobal));
            _isMultiSelectTreeViewLeftButtonHandlerRegistered = true;
        }

        DataTrigger dataTrigger = new DataTrigger();
        dataTrigger.Binding = new Binding("IsHilighted");
        dataTrigger.Value = true;
        dataTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(TreeViewItem.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown)));

        treeView.ItemContainerStyle.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);
```

**Edited code:**

```
 <TreeView Name="TreeViewSelectScopeStudy" MinHeight="24" Margin="7" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TvItemRootPssTreeViewRoot.ChildsView}" Height="Auto"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"> 

            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsHilighted}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <TreeView.Resources>
                <!--<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsHilighted}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to set the Style.Trigger too soon, before the template has been applied. If you apply the Trigger after the `FrameWorkElement` you are targeting has fully loaded you'll probably find that the `ItemStyleContainer` is no longer null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx

Implementing `OnApplyTemplate` for your `FrameworkElement` should hook you in after the ItemStyleContainer has been set as it is called after the Visual Tree has been rendered.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate.aspx

Comment: Hi Ringer, Thanks. I'm not totally sure but I think that all the xaml should have been be processed on "Initialized". I try to put on "OnLoaded" without success. I can override OnApplyTemplate but I would hilighly prefer not to do so because I want to keep my code generic. Deriving from TreeView would affect standard TreeView utilization (I will have to instantiate my own class each time I want to do what I'm doing now).

Comment: Hi Eric, OnInitialized only means that it's the Element has passed through the constructor so all the properties have been initialized. It doesn't guarantee that all elements on the visual tree have been rendered. See here under Initialized second paragraph. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx

Comment: I just made the test: using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MultiSimAnalysis
{
 public class Test3 : TreeView
 {
  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
   base.OnApplyTemplate();

   Debug.Print(this.ItemContainerStyle.ToString());
  }
 }
}
... and using Test3 instead of TreeView in XAML but I get the same NullReferenceException.

Comment: It sounds like I'm trying to reference the wrong style ??? I think that I'm ok with Initialize but I will continue with "Loaded" until I found my bug to make sure I'm ok. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Silly question, but does your Control actually have any Items in it? I don't remember off the top of my head if the ItemsStyleContainer will even link the style until it has something in it or not.

Comment: I found my answer... I write it now ! YUEs there were elements in it.

Comment: I still don't know how to extract the actual Selected Item style (TreeViewItem style of the selected item) ??? Note that ItemContainerStyle has precedence of resource style but the system will also merge any properties that are exclusive to each of the styles.

Comment: try this instead `<Setter property="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>`

Comment: Thanks Ringer. I change the SystemsColors.HilightBrushKey but I still don't know how to know programmatically (and don't know if it is feasilble_ to read what brush will be applied finally as the rendered background for selected item. But I think I will die not knowing it. :-) ! Thanks !